# Is "double checked locking" broken here in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I find an example for double checked locking.

However, I think this example is invalid because it's possible that another thread may see a non-null reference to a DoorControlManage object of door 1 but see the default values for fields of the DoorControlManage object of door 1 rather than the values set in the constructor.
(Ref: [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html))

Could you let me know whether I am right?

Thanks a lot!

```
public class DoorControlManager {
    private static HashMap<Integer, DoorControlManager> mInstances = new HashMap<>();

    public static DoorControlManager getInstance(int door) {
        if (!mInstances.containsKey(door)) {
            synchronized (mInstances) {
                if (!mInstances.containsKey(door)) {
                    mInstances.put(slotId, new DoorControlManager(door));
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstances.get(slotId);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Replacing a simple field with a `HashMap` is *definitely* a non-trivial change that potentially changes everything. I don't know for sure that it'll break, but I'd be at least wary of using a simple `HashMap` with unsynchronized read access this way. It's better to use a map that's built for multithreaded access, like `ConcurrentHashMap` and simply use `mInstances.computeIfAbsent(slotId, () -> new DoorControlManager(door))`.

Comment: I correct my comment: the `DoorControlManager` instance created should be fully intialized before it is added so "default values instead of constructor parameters" should not happen. Additionally, if this is the ony write access to the map that _should_ be ok as well since it is synchronized (i.e. it shouldn't break the map like unsynchronized writes could) but since read access (`containsKey()` and `get()` ) is not synchronized those might not work as intended.

Comment: Thanks Joachim and Thomas. Hi @Thomas, could you explain more about whyt the DoorControlManager instance created should be fully intialized before it is added. Thanks.

Comment: That's how Java works: before making the instance available to the caller all initialization code will have run (i.e. all initializer blocks and the constructor). You _could_ break initialization or get partially initialized object by having the constructor put the `this` reference somewhere before it is done but this doesn't seem to happen here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this code is broken, though not for the normal reason.

In this case, you have different threads accessing `HashMap` without proper synchronization.  Since `HashMap` is not a thread-safe class, this is not thread-safe.   It is possible that the first `containsKey` call will see stale values the internals of the map, and behave in *unspecified* (implementation dependent) ways.

Making "simple" changes to concurrency sensitive code can completely destroy the properties that make the original version thread-safe.  If you are going to attempt to write "clever" code like this, you **need to** have a deep understanding of Java concurrency ... and how the Java Memory Model *really* works.

---

There are a couple of ways that this code could be written correctly:

1. Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and implement the `getInstance` method as:

   ```
   return mInstances.computeIfAbsent(
       slotId, () -> new DoorControlManager(door));
   ```
2. Keep using a `HashMap` and don't use the DCL pattern.  Simply lock before testing.

---

Note that DCL initialization pattern in Java 5+ is not broken, **provided that** the you are initializing a *single field* **and** the field is declared as `volatile`.  But there are other (better) ways to achieve the same effect, so its use is **not recommended**.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I have one question for you saying "It is possible that the first containsKey call will see stale values the internals of the map, and behave in unspecified (implementation dependent) ways." Does it means DoorControlManager might be created again on Thread B even though it's already created and put in mInstances HashMap?

Comment: No.  Because you synchronize before the second `containsKey` call.  The problem is actually worse.  The first `containsKey` might do something bizarre like throw an NPE, or go into an infinite loop, or ... return the wrong `DoorControlManager`.  Figuring out what is possible would entail exhaustive analysis of the `HashMap` implementation in >your< version of Java.

Comment: It might also be possible that it returns the correct `DoorControlManager` but some of its instance fields are stale.  It depends on how the rest of the class is defined.